# Error in min max interval of string extraction

Tags: r, string

I am trying to extract a name from a character string. The text looks like this:

```
Rouw, Anna Marie;Defendant;
```

And my code looks like this:

```
str_extract(data[1,2], "(\\D| ){4, 50}(?<=;Defendant;)")
```

And it has given me this error:

```
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL)
```

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to remove the space between 4 and 50, thank you!

Comment: Try `str_extract(str1, "(?<=, )[^;]+")`

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespace in a brace.

```
{4, 50} -> {4,50}
```